# jQuery effect to open a dialog out of another element and close it into that element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-effects

I want to show my jQuery `dialog` out of another element and hide it into that element.

How should I implement this? Is there any effect to do this?

Comment: you specifically want a dialog?  this is a modal window.

Comment: I want an `effect` to assign it to the `dialog's` `show` option

Comment: excuse me I think I had a bad understanding from the effects concept, I don't think an effect itself can do this, it needs a more complex recipe.

Comment: Here's a great cheatsheet that I use all the time when using jquery: http://www.futurecolors.ru/jquery/

Answer (score 0):

You can bind an effect onto the event that caused the dialog to show.  You can even create custom events.  Here is a great explanation on the subject: http://learn.jquery.com/events/handling-events/

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to use the `position`, `show` and `hide` properties of the object argument  of the `.dialog` method to do the trick.